# Когда лучше использовать статичное объявление переменных

Tags: java

Когда лучше объявлять переменные через static? 
 Или лучше потом объявить в другом классе, ссылку на класс, вот так:

```
public Server sr = new Server();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Статическая переменная принадлежит классу и не зависит от текущего экземпляра (если он вообще есть). Это некоторая принадлежность класса. Если класс ведет учет созданных копий, то у него может быть приватное статическое свойство "счетчик". Честно говоря, я не вижу смысла в обычных статических переменных и методах; точнее, он есть, но затрудняет некоторые аспекты тестирования, поэтому я стараюсь обходиться без статики вообще.

Конкретно в яве отдельным пластом лежат константы, которые объявляются, как финальные статические переменные. Задача константы - один раз определить значение на весь рантайм, которое потом не может изменяться, например, текущее окружение (PRODUCTION / DEVELOPMENT / TESTING) или количество постов на странице (в данный момент оно всегда равно Х, но потом, возможно, команда пересмотрит это значение, и чтобы не менять его в тысяче строк, проще один раз задать его константой). Часто в константы (да и просто статические переменные) помещают не только просто enum'ы / строки, но и какие-то объекты, которые должны существовать в единственном числе, вышеописанный сервер и логгер - хорошие примеры таких объектов, которые предположительно существуют в единственном экземпляре в программе. Однако это немного отходит от понятия статических свойств как характеристик класса, и, опять же, я предпочитаю осуществлять такие вещи через контейнер (DI) - это снижает уровень зависимостей компонентов в системе.

Таким образом, статические свойства в яве делятся на константы и просто свойства, и их задача - держать какие-либо сведения, принадлежащие к классу или то, что существует в программе в единственном числе (проблемы такого подхода я уже описал). Если у вам нужен просто какой-то объект, нет смысла задавать его статическим свойством, а класс не должен носить в статических свойствах то, что к нему не относится.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне согласен с предыдущим оратором, но хотелось бы добавить.

Самый, пожалуй, частый повод применить статическую переменную, это использование Singleton паттерна, другими словами если вам необходимо, чтоб в рамках одной JVM был создан только один экземпляр какого-то класса и не более, например для целей синхронизации или глобального кеширования в многопоточной среде.